# How to get the available area codes?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a pretty complex MySQL query for me.

what i have is a table of phone numbers in the format of a US phone number `8153216458`.

Example:

```
TABLE: numbers(number)
4512163215
4512158211
4512110579
8812163215
9405462136
3021548641
```

What i want is to list the available area codes ( as i'm selling numbers ) without repeating them, Some query that is based on the first 3 digits & finally ordered correctly.

```
Output:
302
451
881
940
```

Any solution? i don't mind if it's still using php manipulation.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct substring(number, 1, 3)
  from numbers;
```

Or, as mentioned by Jeff in the comments, `left` is also an option:

```
select distinct left(number, 3)
  from numbers;
```

Check out [documentation for string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) on MySQL.

Comment: `left()` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) is an option as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! You should add **AS 'number'** for noobs like me to understand :)

Comment: oh you mean like in my answer below?...the one that only has one vote up? :( lol...all these experts like pablo keep beating me to the punch

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

select distinct substring(number, 0, 3) as 'number'
from numbers
order by number